# Connect Power BI to an external web API without using the desktop tool

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to connect Power BI web to an external web API without using the Power BI desktop and create a report totally online, without installing the desktop tool?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only build a Dataset in the Power BI Service from flat files.  Everything else requires using Power BI Desktop to build your Dataset.

Once you have a Dataset you can build reports in either Power BI Desktop or on the web.